# Is a one time session key okay?

Tags: authentication

I was wondering if the following would be okay.

I want to have users connect to a server running SSL that authenticates user credentials, and sends them back a one time session key.  Users can then connect to a non-encrypted server and use this session key to login to their account.

One possible situation that could be sticky would be a classic MITB, and it would be easier due to having no encryption.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most justifications for a non-encrypted sessions / information serving stems from not owning visitor (client) security concerns. i.e., "My server / my data won't be harmed, so I'm okay". If that's all you want and you're only serving content to authenticated/authorized users (not allowing them to change anything), then your strategy will work.

So I suggest you use encryption. Getting and using a LetsEncrypt certificate costs nothing these days (other than a few minutes of your time). It won't be long before browsers and search engines start warning users away from unencrypted sites.

> ... classic MITB, and it would easier due to having no encryption

For web applications, MITB has practically the same impact as client compromise. So "encryption" or other defenses don't help at all.

From the [Wikipedia - MITB Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-browser):

> A MitB attack will be successful irrespective of whether security mechanisms such as SSL/PKI and/or two or three-factor Authentication solutions are in place. A MitB attack may be countered by utilising out-of-band transaction verification, although ...

Comment: Okay great to know.  This is for a app message service.

Answer (score 0):

You can add server side validation to validate with OTP at once. if OTP verified once then drop key where Comparison is happen. then it may be, because your session will be success and attacker who get OTP via MITM the will send request to  authenticate then server will not be able to verify because verification key is dropped from server side.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean here.